# Why using char type as index for looping gives unexpected results?

Tags: c, z80, cpm

Bear in mind this is an old version of the C compiler: CP/M for Z80.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char i = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("0x%04x | ", i);
    } while (++ i);       
}
```

Expected:

> 0x0000 | 0x0001 | 0x0002 | 0x0003 | 0x0004 | 0x0005 | 0x0006 | 0x0007 | 0x0008 | 0x0009 | 0x000A | 0x000B | 0x000C | 0x000D | 0x000E | 0x000F | 0x0010 | 0x0011 | 0x0012 | 0x0013 | 0x0014 | 0x0015 | 0x0016 | 0x0017 | 0x0018 | 0x0019 | 0x001A | 0x001B | 0x001C | 0x001D | 0x001E | 0x001F | 0x0020 | 0x0021 | 0x0022 | 0x0023 | 0x0024 | 0x0025 | 0x0026 | 0x0027 | 0x0028 | 0x0029 | 0x002A | 0x002B | 0x002C | 0x002D | 0x002E | 0x002F | 0x0030 | 0x0031 | 0x0032 | 0x0033 | 0x0034 | 0x0035 | 0x0036 | 0x0037 | 0x0038 | 0x0039 | 0x003A | 0x003B | 0x003C | 0x003D | 0x003E | 0x003F | 0x0040 | 0x0041 | 0x0042 | 0x0043 | 0x0044 | 0x0045 | 0x0046 | 0x0047 | 0x0048 | 0x0049 | 0x004A | 0x004B | 0x004C | 0x004D | 0x004E | 0x004F | 0x0050 | 0x0051 | 0x0052 | 0x0053 | 0x0054 | 0x0055 | 0x0056 | 0x0057 | 0x0058 | 0x0059 | 0x005A | 0x005B | 0x005C | 0x005D | 0x005E | 0x005F | 0x0060 | 0x0061 | 0x0062 | 0x0063 | 0x0064 | 0x0065 | 0x0066 | 0x0067 | 0x0068 | 0x0069 | 0x006A | 0x006B | 0x006C | 0x006D | 0x006E | 0x006F | 0x0070 | 0x0071 | 0x0072 | 0x0073 | 0x0074 | 0x0075 | 0x0076 | 0x0077 | 0x0078 | 0x0079 | 0x007A | 0x007B | 0x007C | 0x007D | 0x007E | 0x007F | 0x0080 | 0x0081 | 0x0082 | 0x0083 | 0x0084 | 0x0085 | 0x0086 | 0x0087 | 0x0088 | 0x0089 | 0x008A | 0x008B | 0x008C | 0x008D | 0x008E | 0x008F | 0x0090 | 0x0091 | 0x0092 | 0x0093 | 0x0094 | 0x0095 | 0x0096 | 0x0097 | 0x0098 | 0x0099 | 0x009A | 0x009B | 0x009C | 0x009D | 0x009E | 0x009F | 0x00A0 | 0x00A1 | 0x00A2 | 0x00A3 | 0x00A4 | 0x00A5 | 0x00A6 | 0x00A7 | 0x00A8 | 0x00A9 | 0x00AA | 0x00AB | 0x00AC | 0x00AD | 0x00AE | 0x00AF | 0x00B0 | 0x00B1 | 0x00B2 | 0x00B3 | 0x00B4 | 0x00B5 | 0x00B6 | 0x00B7 | 0x00B8 | 0x00B9 | 0x00BA | 0x00BB | 0x00BC | 0x00BD | 0x00BE | 0x00BF | 0x00C0 | 0x00C1 | 0x00C2 | 0x00C3 | 0x00C4 | 0x00C5 | 0x00C6 | 0x00C7 | 0x00C8 | 0x00C9 | 0x00CA | 0x00CB | 0x00CC | 0x00CD | 0x00CE | 0x00CF | 0x00D0 | 0x00D1 | 0x00D2 | 0x00D3 | 0x00D4 | 0x00D5 | 0x00D6 | 0x00D7 | 0x00D8 | 0x00D9 | 0x00DA | 0x00DB | 0x00DC | 0x00DD | 0x00DE | 0x00DF | 0x00E0 | 0x00E1 | 0x00E2 | 0x00E3 | 0x00E4 | 0x00E5 | 0x00E6 | 0x00E7 | 0x00E8 | 0x00E9 | 0x00EA | 0x00EB | 0x00EC | 0x00ED | 0x00EE | 0x00EF | 0x00F0 | 0x00F1 | 0x00F2 | 0x00F3 | 0x00F4 | 0x00F5 | 0x00F6 | 0x00F7 | 0x00F8 | 0x00F9 | 0x00FA | 0x00FB | 0x00FC | 0x00FD | 0x00FE | 0x00FF |

Actual:

> 0x0A00 | 0x0A01 | 0x0A02 | 0x0A03 | 0x0A04 | 0x0A05 | 0x0A06 | 0x0A07 | 0x0A08 | 0x0A09 | 0x0A0A | 0x0A0B | 0x0A0C | 0x0A0D | 0x0A0E | 0x0A0F | 0x0A10 | 0x0A11 | 0x0A12 | 0x0A13 | 0x0A14 | 0x0A15 | 0x0A16 | 0x0A17 | 0x0A18 | 0x0A19 | 0x0A1A | 0x0A1B | 0x0A1C | 0x0A1D | 0x0A1E | 0x0A1F | 0x0A20 | 0x0A21 | 0x0A22 | 0x0A23 | 0x0A24 | 0x0A25 | 0x0A26 | 0x0A27 | 0x0A28 | 0x0A29 | 0x0A2A | 0x0A2B | 0x0A2C | 0x0A2D | 0x0A2E | 0x0A2F | 0x0A30 | 0x0A31 | 0x0A32 | 0x0A33 | 0x0A34 | 0x0A35 | 0x0A36 | 0x0A37 | 0x0A38 | 0x0A39 | 0x0A3A | 0x0A3B | 0x0A3C | 0x0A3D | 0x0A3E | 0x0A3F | 0x0A40 | 0x0A41 | 0x0A42 | 0x0A43 | 0x0A44 | 0x0A45 | 0x0A46 | 0x0A47 | 0x0A48 | 0x0A49 | 0x0A4A | 0x0A4B | 0x0A4C | 0x0A4D | 0x0A4E | 0x0A4F | 0x0A50 | 0x0A51 | 0x0A52 | 0x0A53 | 0x0A54 | 0x0A55 | 0x0A56 | 0x0A57 | 0x0A58 | 0x0A59 | 0x0A5A | 0x0A5B | 0x0A5C | 0x0A5D | 0x0A5E | 0x0A5F | 0x0A60 | 0x0A61 | 0x0A62 | 0x0A63 | 0x0A64 | 0x0A65 | 0x0A66 | 0x0A67 | 0x0A68 | 0x0A69 | 0x0A6A | 0x0A6B | 0x0A6C | 0x0A6D | 0x0A6E | 0x0A6F | 0x0A70 | 0x0A71 | 0x0A72 | 0x0A73 | 0x0A74 | 0x0A75 | 0x0A76 | 0x0A77 | 0x0A78 | 0x0A79 | 0x0A7A | 0x0A7B | 0x0A7C | 0x0A7D | 0x0A7E | 0x0A7F | 0x0A80 | 0x0A81 | 0x0A82 | 0x0A83 | 0x0A84 | 0x0A85 | 0x0A86 | 0x0A87 | 0x0A88 | 0x0A89 | 0x0A8A | 0x0A8B | 0x0A8C | 0x0A8D | 0x0A8E | 0x0A8F | 0x0A90 | 0x0A91 | 0x0A92 | 0x0A93 | 0x0A94 | 0x0A95 | 0x0A96 | 0x0A97 | 0x0A98 | 0x0A99 | 0x0A9A | 0x0A9B | 0x0A9C | 0x0A9D | 0x0A9E | 0x0A9F | 0x0AA0 | 0x0AA1 | 0x0AA2 | 0x0AA3 | 0x0AA4 | 0x0AA5 | 0x0AA6 | 0x0AA7 | 0x0AA8 | 0x0AA9 | 0x0AAA | 0x0AAB | 0x0AAC | 0x0AAD | 0x0AAE | 0x0AAF | 0x0AB0 | 0x0AB1 | 0x0AB2 | 0x0AB3 | 0x0AB4 | 0x0AB5 | 0x0AB6 | 0x0AB7 | 0x0AB8 | 0x0AB9 | 0x0ABA | 0x0ABB | 0x0ABC | 0x0ABD | 0x0ABE | 0x0ABF | 0x0AC0 | 0x0AC1 | 0x0AC2 | 0x0AC3 | 0x0AC4 | 0x0AC5 | 0x0AC6 | 0x0AC7 | 0x0AC8 | 0x0AC9 | 0x0ACA | 0x0ACB | 0x0ACC | 0x0ACD | 0x0ACE | 0x0ACF | 0x0AD0 | 0x0AD1 | 0x0AD2 | 0x0AD3 | 0x0AD4 | 0x0AD5 | 0x0AD6 | 0x0AD7 | 0x0AD8 | 0x0AD9 | 0x0ADA | 0x0ADB | 0x0ADC | 0x0ADD | 0x0ADE | 0x0ADF | 0x0AE0 | 0x0AE1 | 0x0AE2 | 0x0AE3 | 0x0AE4 | 0x0AE5 | 0x0AE6 | 0x0AE7 | 0x0AE8 | 0x0AE9 | 0x0AEA | 0x0AEB | 0x0AEC | 0x0AED | 0x0AEE | 0x0AEF | 0x0AF0 | 0x0AF1 | 0x0AF2 | 0x0AF3 | 0x0AF4 | 0x0AF5 | 0x0AF6 | 0x0AF7 | 0x0AF8 | 0x0AF9 | 0x0AFA | 0x0AFB | 0x0AFC | 0x0AFD | 0x0AFE | 0x0AFF |

What am I doing wrong?

Assembly:

```
    cseg
?59999:
    defb    48,120,37,48,52,120,32,124,32,0

main@:
    ld  c,0
@0:
    push    bc
    push    bc
    ld  bc,?59999
    push    bc
    ld  hl,2
    call    printf
    pop bc
    pop bc
    pop bc
    inc c
    jp  nz,@0
    ret


    public  main@
    extrn   printf

    end
```

Comment: Is this a minimal example, or does `printf("%x", (char)0);` output `A00`?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an endless loop and cause a runtime error even on Z80? Why stops the output at `0x0AFF|` then? Or is it just an example to show the output?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio now I understand it stops at 0x00FF because that's the higher a char can go. The reason it prints 0x0AFF is because printf("%04X"... expects a int or unsigned but not a char. This program is just a exercise I am doing for very small arrays using char as index opposed to the native integer that the compiler defaults to.

Comment: Show your assembly.

Comment: @TomServo, I've edit the post and added the assembly code as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Golly. LONG time since I used a z80 C compiler, and most were buggy as [unprintable] back then.
I would suggest that you dump the assembler if the compiler allows. My GUESS is that internally the char is being promoted to a 16 bit INT with indeterminate upper bits set.

The problem is that %04X expects an integer - not a char.

You might try forcing the compiler to play nice by explicitly casting the char to an int - i.e.

printf("0x%04x | ", (int) i);

Comment: The usual integer promotions already convert the char argument to printf to an int. Note also that %x expects an unsigned int.

Comment: You've nailed it! Casting to int or unsigned will give the expected result. I believe it works because the compiler makes no distinction as long as it's a native 16bit type. Thanks!

Comment: @vDom: Instead of a cast, try using the `hh` length modifier in the conversion specifier - `%04hhx`.

Comment: @JohnBode didn't work. The problem is this version of C is more like K&R C than C99 or C11. It'd be cool if it worked.

Comment: To Paul Hankin: yes the compilers SHOULD do this to comply with C standards. Back in the day I coded professionally to Z80 and 6809 targets using C. No compiler was free of bugs of exactly this sort. Or the total inability to compile some C constructions successfully at all. I remember an array of pointers to functions - trivial in assembler, impossible with the compiler I had.

Answer (score 2):

Most probable thing is that, as being an old 8 bit compiler, it is not converting the `char` typed `i` variable into an `int` and it is just pushing the `bc` register (assuming your function will not use the high part, which is simply not true, as your function (`printf()`) expects a whole `int` as parameter) which you don't know what it has in the `b` register.  The compiler is using the full `bc` register to print, as you use `%x` format, which is for an `int` parameter, and this explains the presence of the high byte as `0x0a` in the output (and which doesn't appear anywhere in your assembler listing).  Later versions of the standard begun to convert every `short` and `char`  arguments to `int` in order probably to avoid this kind of issue.

Try this code, and see if that solves the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char i = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("0x%04x | ", (int) i);
    } while (++ i);       
}
```

(I cannot check here, as I have z80 computer, but not a C compiler for it)

## Edit

After checking the assembler code, the compiler output just pushes the complete `bc` register into the stack, in which the lower part (the`c` register) comes from the character you want to print, but the `b` register was previously loaded with the high byte of the `59999` pointer to the array of characters of the format string, which happens to be `0xea`.  So, I got stranged at the output, that should be probably `0xea00, 0xea01, 0xea02, ...` and not the output you have.  Have you recompiled the source to get the assembler output and the output refers to a different compilation?

To dig a little more I'd need the code of the `printf()` function, which I assume you don't have.  But that seems that converting the parameter to `(int)` before passing it to the `printf()` function should solve the problem.

Comment: hahaha  @mcleod_ideafix, good point your edition! :) that means you have read it thoroughly :)

Comment: @mcleod, yes converting to (int) solves the problem. The assembler output is the result of the compiled c code I used in this example. I think I might have printf()'s source code. I need some time to find it...